# Extending Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

Ok, here's my issue - rather simple, though I'm not sure how to go about it (and avoid downloading tens of unnecessary gigabytes).

I've downloaded and installed "Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone" (`wpsdkv80_enu1`).

I'm wondering what I should download/install in order to fully support development of Desktop apps, or plain Windows 8 applications. (apart from Windows phone, I mean).

Any ideas? (preferably with links?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Visual Studio Express products, there's one Visual Studio for each kind of application:

- Windows Phone
- Desktop
- Windows 8 Store
- Web

So you have to install multiple Visual Studio Express, using different versions.

For desktop: **Express 2012 for Windows Desktop**

See http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products#product-express-summary

Comment: Really?! Doesn't sound practical at all - I thought all of the versions shared a core (which it obviously does) plus *something else* (platform-specific SDKs, etc), which could be downloaded separately. Guess I was wrong...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Yeah, of course they do share the same base. But you'll have to pay to get everything bundled a in a single Visual Studio. Remember VS2012 Express is a great product that is **free** to use.

Comment: You get what you paid for with Visual Studio Express Edition ;) If you're adventurous, you could try running the installer from the download site instead of downloading the ISO's. Maybe you'll save 50 MB. But on the flipside, you won't have the ISO in case you need to re-install.

Comment: @ken2k Well, I do get your point... Though, coming from an Objective-C/Cocoa background, I guess I got used to Apple's pricing policy of their IDE. My bad. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to download a new ISO (or two). Just make VERY sure you download the right ISO. There is one for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8, which allows you to develop Windows Store apps and you need a developer account and license for it. There's ALSO a Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop, which allows you to develop applications like on Windows 7.